# Замена NAN на нужный символ

Tags: c

Есть мат.функция, допустим у=1/х
на ввод подаем х
на вывод у
если подать х=0
консоль выдаст nan!
как заменить nan на нужный мне символ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    double x,y;
    scanf ("%lf",&x);
    y=1/x;

   //вот тут затык 
if ( y == NAN ){
   //-----/\------
   //------|------
   //------|------
    printf ("%lf",&x);
}
else {
    printf ("%lf",&x);
}

}
```

Comment: Заменить - никак: это разные типы. Выводить вместо nan что-то свое? проверять на `NaN` и если так, выводить не число, а свою строку.

Comment: как проверить на NAN?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan

Comment: `NaN` это что-то новенькое (какой ОС и компилятором пользуетесь?). Должно быть `inf` (бесконечность)

Comment: да не суть инф или нан, суть заменить в консоле на   -  !

Comment: Огонь! спасибо Harry!

Comment: @avp, вроде плюсы не гарантируют работу с NaN (про бесконечности не помню)? Там надо какой-то флаг компиляции включить, чтобы математика нормально работала с ними.

Comment: @Harry, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а при чем тут плюсы? Это же формат представления плавающих и значения вырабатываются аппаратурой

Comment: @avp, при отпимизаторе. Он может какие-то выражения считать заведомо истинными или заведомо ложными, из-за чего получится не то, что должно было. Примерно как с переполнением знаковых int'ов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, к счастью вопрос про Си (но не удивлюсь, если и в него молодые дарования уже внесли свою дурь)

Comment: @avp, а в таких вопросах плюсы от си могут отличаться? И вообще, я прав про отпимизатор и NaN или что-то путаю?

Comment: @Qwertiy, про оптимизацию и NaN я не знаю. И про могут ли (на мой взгляд не должны) различаться, тоже не знаю. Вообще, я мат. функциями (и даже double) по работе уже 100 лет не пользовался. / Вот GNU про это пишет https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Comment: @elMuertodeMederti, напишите вот так `if (isinf(y) || isnan(y))
    printf("Bad result\n");
  else
    printf ("x = %lf   y = %lf\n", x, y);`  / Ну, конкретные символы для вывода сами придумайте

Comment: [isfinite()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isfinite) - возвращает целое нулевое значение, если аргумент `NaN` или бесконечность, иначе ненулевое.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ проверки на NaN - сравнить на (не)равенство с собой: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##VYvLDoIwFET3/YoRN5hoZC2PvRv@oZYraVIuhLYRa/z2WiIL3UwyZ86oaTr1SsW416yM7wiVHq2bSQ6NEN5q7sFyIDtJRbCuK4XQ7DBIzflBvATQjf5mCMsRzzQCSjOaBssaX7IZAXWi5w3qO/KAXY1wSC3dRu9QVciuDg9p0cr2gmwlYQ3izpRJJGPpz/9ZE5/J@ZlRlOIdY4HiAw)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x, y;

  cin >> x >> y;

  double z = x / y;

  if (z != z)
    cout << "It was NaN: " << z << endl;
  else
    cout << z << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```
0 0
```

```
It was NaN: -nan
```

Тем не менее, насколько я помню, оптимизации компилятора по умолчанию не гарантируют корректную работу с NaN - требуется добавить какой-то флаг.

Comment: Ну, для `inf` (который должен быть у ТС, которому все равно, что NaN, что INF, а главное как-то заменить это на символ) этот код не сработает

Comment: @avp, спросили про NaN - я ответил про NaN. А inf надо как-то по-другому определять.